# Linear independence of functions from positive definite kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions, convex-hulls, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $S$ be a finite set and $M_p(S)\subset \mathbb{R}^{|S|}$ the set of probabilities on $S$.

Define the positive-definite kernel:
$$k:M_p(S)\times M_p(S)\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\,\qquad(\nu,\mu)\mapsto k(\nu,\mu):=\left(\sum_{s\in S}\nu(s)\mu(t)\right)^2=(\nu^T\mu)^2,$$
wherein the final equality $\nu\,,\mu$ are considered vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{|S|}$.

This positive-definite kernel induces maps $M_p(S)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, one for each $\nu\in M_p(S)$:

$$K_\nu:M_p(S)\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\,\qquad \mu\mapsto k(\nu,\mu).$$

> *Are these maps linearly independent?*

Without the square,
$$K_\nu=\sum_{s\in S}\nu(s)K_{\delta^s},$$
and there is linear dependence, but I am looking for linear independence.

---

Some thoughts. Consider a finite set $\{\nu_1,\nu_2,\dots,\nu_m\}\subset M_p(S)$ and complex numbers $(\alpha_i)_{i=1}^m$ such that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_iK_{\nu_i}=0.$$
For each $s\in S$, we have:
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i K_{\nu_i}(\delta^s)  =0
  \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i \nu_i(s)^2  =0 
\end{align*}
Consider, for a pair $s_a,s_b\in S$:
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i K_{\nu_i}\left(\frac12\delta^{s_a}+\frac12 \delta^{s_b}\right)  =0 
  \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i\nu_i(s_a)\nu_i(s_b) & =0. 
 \end{align*}
Summing over $s_a\in S$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i \nu_i(s_b)=0.$$
Considering where $u_S$ is the uniform distrition
$$\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i K_{\nu_i}\left(u_S\right)\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i=0.$$

---

As per the comments, it is sufficient to show that for any finite subset $\{\nu_1,\dots,\nu_m\}\subset M_p(S)$, that the Gram matrix $G\in M_m(\mathbb{R})$:

$$G_{ij}=\langle\nu_i,\nu_j\rangle^2=(\nu_i^T\nu_j)^2$$

is (strictly) positive definite.

---

The bounty winner's answer gives for $\nu_1=(1,0)$, $\nu_2=(0,1)$, $\nu_3=(1/2,1/2)$, and $\nu=(1/3,2/3)$:

$$K_\nu=-\frac19 K_{\nu_1}+\frac{2}{9}K_{\nu_2}+\frac49 K_{\nu_3}.$$

Comment: there's a lot of notation here, and e.g. $G$ is never defined so I could be missing some things, but I suspect there's a simple solution-- being positive definite, write out the Gram Matrix $\mathbf G\succ \mathbf 0$.  If the functions $K_{v_i}$ are linearly dependent then that linear relation holds when you specialize to any $\mu$ in its image, but that's equivalent to $\mathbf x^T G = \mathbf 0^T$ for some $\mathbf x \neq \mathbf 0$ which is impossible since $\det\big(\mathbf G\big)\gt 0$.

Comment: The $G$ was a typo sorry.

Comment: @user8675309 how does the linear kernel $(\nu,\mu)\mapsto \nu^T\mu$ fare in that argument?

Comment: The argument is silent in that case.  If you use the standard dot product for your kernel, and collect relevant ones in a Gram matrix $\mathbf G'$ then  $\mathbf G =  \mathbf G' \circ \mathbf G'$.  The issue is $\mathbf G'\succ \mathbf 0 \longrightarrow \mathbf G \succ \mathbf 0$ but the reverse doesn't hold per se-- $\mathbf G\succ \mathbf 0$ doesn't tell us much about $\mathbf G'$-- all we know is it is spsd, being a Gram Matrix.

Comment: @user8675309 this isn't material I am necessarily familiar with. If you want to write up an answer you will need to do some explanation in it. If you want to answer I'll give you some bounty for your answer.

Comment: @user8675309 I understand the material (Gram, etc.) but I don't follow your argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the Gram matrix is positive definite, it is enough to note that it is the Hadamard product of the Gram matrix corresponding to the usual inner product with itself (which is itself positive definite) and then to use the [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem) .

Edit:
If you begin with $v_i$ which are not linearly independent, there is no reason why the Gram matrix corresponding to $K$ should be non-singular as it is the Gram matrix of $e_i\otimes e_i$. For instance,  take $e_1=(1,0),e_2=(0,1)$ and the set $\{e_1,e_2,\frac{1}{2}e_1+\frac{1}{2}e_2,\frac{1}{3}e_1+\frac{2}{3}e_2\}$. The Gram matrix for the inner product is
$$G=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{3}\\
0&1&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{2}{3}\\
\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{3}&\frac{2}{3}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{5}{9}
\end{pmatrix}$$
so that $G\circ G$, the Gram matrix for our kernel is
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{9}\\
0&1&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{4}{9}\\
\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}\\
\frac{1}{9}&\frac{4}{9}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{25}{81}
\end{pmatrix}$$
which has determinant $0$.

Comment: Thank you but I don't think this is enough. It needs to be shown that the Gram matrix is strictly positive definite. The Gram matrix corresponding to the usual inner product is not strictly positive definite.

Comment: I am terribly sorry if I have made an error, but I checked my computation with Mathematica and I believe it is correct. Regardless, if you agree that $G\circ G$ is the Gram matrix of $v_1\otimes v_1,\cdots v_n\otimes v_n$ then I will obtain a singular matrix by letting all of the $v_i$ lie in $V$, a subspace of dimension $m$ and then taking $n=m^2+1$ vectors, since this will be more vectors than the dimension of $V\otimes V$.

Comment: Apologies when I checked the determinant I must have made an error.

Comment: Will be giving the bounty, I think I have to wait.